# Координаты центра экрана устройства с iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Почему центр экрана всегда ниже "ожидаемого" центра экрана устройства? Может есть какая то особенность, о которой я не знаю?

```
self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

[self.activityIndicator setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
```

Так же пробовал вычислять центр `self.activityIndicator.center` следующими способами

```
CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) / 2.0f,
            CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) / 2.0f);

CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) / 2.0f,
            CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) / 2.0f);

CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds) / 2.0f,
            CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds) / 2.0f);

self.view.center;

self.tableView.center;
```

[image]

Comment: Полезней было бы увидеть код размещения этого индикатора в данном случае. Учитываются ли его размеры при размещении?

Comment: @Deadkenny пробовал `[self.tableView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];` и `[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];` Размеры не учитываются, задается только центр

Comment: Да, надо знать на какой вьюхе лежит индикатор. А то он по центру относительно контроллера, а не окна.

Comment: сдвиньте на topLayoutGuide, все на UITableView сдвигается на него, предполагаю, что косяк ровно в 64 пикселя, поскольку на UIViewCoщntroller 0 - это как раз 64 пикселя в координатах UIScreen. И не проще ли писать bounds.size.width вместо CGRectGetWidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сдвиньте на topLayoutGuide. Все на основном UIView внутри UIViewController сдвигается на него, предполагаю, что косяк ровно в 64 пикселя, поскольку на любом UIViewController 0 - это как раз 64 пикселя в координатах UIScreen. И не проще ли писать bounds.size.width вместо CGRectGetWidth?

Comment: Можно подробнее, предполагается что `self.topLayoutGuide.length == 64` ?